# Google scholar search query issue

Tags: google-scholar

Last year Economics of Governance (Springer) published an article that I co-authored  titled "Political determinants of fiscal transparency: a panel data empirical investigation". 
Google Scholar  appears to find the article only if I search for the complete title or search for *political determinants of fiscal transparency*. If I enter any other combination of words of the title or the keywords  in the search query the article disappears from the results. 
Even more strangely, Google Scholar does not find the article when I look for *political determinants fiscal transparency*. How is it possible that the word *of* makes such a difference for Google Scholar?

Thank you!

P.S. I wrote to the journal and they replied that this is how it is supposed to work, but this answer is not really convincing.

Comment: I don't think anyone is going to be able to answer such a specific question about the inner workings of Google's search engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it disappears: it's probably just ranked low in the general query results.

If you restrict the search with keywords "political determinants fiscal transparency" to "results since 2017" (https://scholar.google.com/scholar?as_ylo=2017&q=political+determinants+fiscal+transparency&hl=en&as_sdt=0,33) (note the "as_ylo=2017" in the URL), your paper is ranked first.

Comment: Thank you, I checked and the article actually appears at page 23 of the search results. I suppose there is no way to increase the ranking of  paper but wait for citations?

Comment: What would you want in a search?  The paper with most citations, or the paper paired with an algorithm-cheating method to move it up?  For straight Google searching, there are (shady?) outfits who claim they will (for a fee) get your page moved up in the search listings.

Comment: Well, I was not thinking about cheating. I'd want the papers that match my search query better, but it appears that this is not the way Google Scholar's algorithm works